# Resources for learning graphics designing

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend, expression-design

I am not a designer by profession and don't really want to become one [not my cup of tea, I guess]. I want to gain some knowledge on graphics designing [mostly with XAML] so that I can at least work with Expression Design and Blend. Any book or video that can teach me some effects would be good.

What are you favorite resources to learn Expression Design and Expression Blend?
How can you learn to create effects like, shine on the button, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these courses and tutorials. 
**[.Toolbox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/default.aspx)** 
They'll walk you thru various design scenarios and principles.

Just don't be afraid to try things out. Add lots of different layers on top of eachother with different gradients, a small line or curve here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Designing is good when you combine your skills on word,symbols and images to create representation of ideas that creates visual comminucation and representation.

As I know Expression series has the ability to import other design tools like Photoshop and Illustrator.At least you dont need to draw in blend if you're already used them.

Check Microsoft's own Training videos [here](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136535.aspx).

That's all I can find

Hope that makes you a designer :)
Myra

Comment: The problem is that I know what is blend and how to use it. What I don't know is how to use those tools from a practical graphics designer perspective. For ex. how do you make a button shine? Which colors go well together? I understand it is hard work by the designers but I would really like to read some book on graphics designing [even if it is software agnostic].

Comment: There are more available blogs about designing.Perhaps you should check them out like smashingmagazine,psdtuts.